# Choose edges from weighted graph, such that each vertex is an endpoint of one edge, and the sum of edge weights is minimized

Tags: algorithm, graph

For simplication, we can assume that the graph G=(V,E) has 2N vertexes and the answer has N edges.

I have learned that if the graph is bipartite, Hungarian algorithm works well. However, I wonder if there is any nontrivial solution(i.e. a polynomial one) for a general graph.

Any polynomial solutions, as well as a proof of NP Complexity, are welcome.

Comment: If you want every vertex be incident to exactly one edge, then you need to find perfect matching. But perfect matching not always exists even for a graph with even number of vertices.

Comment: @Yola, we can just assume it a complete graph with “missing edge” having a sufficient large weight. Since I just care about polynomial solutions, harmless assumptions are welcome.

Comment: @Yola thank you for the hint of Perfect Matching, I think I’ve got what i want.

Comment: @Yola Please post your “comment” as an answer, and I’ll mark it as accepted galdly. Thanks again.

Comment: Done with link to an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want every vertex be incident to exactly one edge, then you need to find perfect matching. But perfect matching not always exists even for a graph with even number of vertices.

You can see example in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2490130/31462).